# Xcode 3.2.3 - Debugger shows only _string.h

Tags: iphone, xcode

In certain locations in my application, if I place a breakpoint and go to that location the code window jumps me to _string.h (which is locked) to this function.

```
static __inline void *
__inline_memcpy_chk (void *__dest, const void *__src, size_t __len)
```

When I hit Step I am stuck, and all I see is _string.h.  My code still executes and I see my NSLog().

A quick fix is to run in release mode, but in my project I have special code that happens in release.  So this isn't really an option.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by my project being a universal build.  We created an iPhone version of the build and I can walk through the section of my code where I couldn't before. But then I have the issue of not being able to view my variables.

Oddly enough when I go back to the universal build I don't have the problem in my code, and I can debug normally.  Not the greatest fix but at least I can work.